# UN take on ISIS?

Tags: united-nations, islamic-state

As a quick search didn't turn up a clear result on this: did the UNSC or the UNGA (in this order of authority) give any authorizations or make any recommendations on the use of force against ISIS? And if they were not that explicit, what's the strongest thing they said/recommended be done about it?

N.B., it's easy to find UN condemnations of ISIS attacks, e.g. there's [one](https://iraq.un.org/en/212734-security-council-press-statement-recent-terrorist-attacks-iraq) by the UNSC as late as 20 December, 2022.

> The members of the Security Council reiterated that any acts of terrorism are criminal and unjustifiable, regardless of their motivation, wherever, whenever and by whomsoever committed.  They reaffirmed the need for all States to combat by all means, in accordance with the Charter of the United Nations and other obligations under international law, including international human rights law, international refugee law and international humanitarian law, threats to international peace and security caused by terrorist acts.
>
> The members of the Security Council reaffirmed their support for Iraq’s security and the continued fight against terrorism, including against ISIL/Da’esh.

Anything other than "ISIS = very bad, we support Iraqi security and combating terrorism everywhere in accordance with international law" from the UN though?

Comment: The U.N. has not recognized ISIS as a member state or sovereign state, if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security Council [Resolution 2249](https://www.securitycouncilreport.org/atf/cf/%7B65BFCF9B-6D27-4E9C-8CD3-CF6E4FF96FF9%7D/s_res_2249.pdf) asks member states to make efforts against ISIS Terrorism in Syria. 
Excerpt here:

> ... calls upon Member States that have the capacity to do so to take all
> necessary measures, in compliance with international law, in particular with the
> United Nations Charter, as well as international human rights, refugee and
> humanitarian law,

> on the territory under the control of ISIL also known as Da’esh,
> in Syria and Iraq,

> to redouble and coordinate their efforts to prevent and suppress
> terrorist acts committed specifically by ISIL also known as Da’esh

> as well as ANF,
> and all other individuals, groups, undertakings, and entities associated with
> Al Qaeda, and other terrorist groups, as designated by UNSC, and as may further be agreed by the International Syria Support Group
> (ISSG) and endorsed by the UN Security Council, pursuant to the Statement of the
> International Syria Support Group (ISSG) of 14 November,

> and to eradicate the safe
> haven they have established over significant parts of Iraq and Syria

Comment: I guess "eradicate the safe haven" [such and such place] was the stuff not usually contained in other generic condemnations of terrorism.

Comment: @Fizz even the part "redouble and co-ordinate efforts to eradicate terrorism at [this place] specifically by [this organisation]" is quite unique.